# rsync using both --update and --append

Tags: append, rsync, resume

I have a problem using rsync. Actually I want to synchronize 2 folders, one on the server (192.168.1.5) and one on my pc, the rsync command that I use is:

```
rsync -rvzru --exclude=._* xxx@192.168.1.5::Folder /Users/blabla/boh/received
```

It works fine, if a file has been modified on my server it modifies it also on my pc, skipping all the others. Now I want to introduce the resume feature, so I add --append like this:

```
rsync -rvzru --exclude=._* --append xxx@192.168.1.5::Folder /Users/blabla/boh/received
```

I also tried with --partial, but it doesn't work at all, it skips the uncompleted files while updates all the others if there was a modification. If I remove -U from the command the resume works fine, but if I modify a file on the server, I can't see the modification on my PC.

```
rsync -rvzr --exclude=._* --append xxx@192.168.1.5::Folder /Users/blabla/boh/received
```

There's a way to let this work both resuming and updating new files? Thanks